# Extract data from one data frame to another data frame with different row length

Tags: r, match

I have two data.frames as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c("lee","eeu","ees"), B=c("lee","ggu","1su"), C=c(1,1,1)

    A   B C
1 lee lee 1
2 eeu ggu 1
3 ees 1su 1


df2 <- data.frame (X=c("lee","1su","eeu","ggu"), Y=c("3k3","4k4","5k","2ee"), Z=c("ggg","","","ooo"), ZA=c("vvv","","",""))

    X   Y   Z  ZA
1 lee 3k3 ggg vvv
2 1su 4k4        
3 eeu  5k        
4 ggu 2ee ooo
```

I want to expand df1 by matching df1$B with df2$X.  When df1$B = df2$X, I want to add additional rows to the new_df1 with new B = other entries in df2 on the same row, but keeping A and C the same.

new_df1 is expected to be as follows:

```
 A   B  C
lee 3k3 1 ### df1$B1= df2$X1= lee
lee ggg 1
lee vvv 1
eeu 2ee 1 ### df1$B2= df2$X4= ggu
eeu ooo 1
ees 4k4 1 ### df1$B3= df2$X2= lsu
```

My past experience on using lapply seems to be very memory-demanding, is it possible to be done without using lapply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you wnat is a subset of this:

```
require(reshape2)
merge(df1,melt(df2, id.var="X"), by.x="B", by.y="X", all=TRUE)
     B    A  C variable value
1  1su  ees  1        Y   4k4
2  1su  ees  1        Z      
3  1su  ees  1       ZA      
4  ggu  eeu  1        Y   2ee
5  ggu  eeu  1        Z   ooo
6  ggu  eeu  1       ZA      
7  lee  lee  1        Y   3k3
8  lee  lee  1        Z   ggg
9  lee  lee  1       ZA   vvv
10 eeu <NA> NA        Y    5k
11 eeu <NA> NA        Z      
12 eeu <NA> NA       ZA
```

I assigned that object to "M1" (and later noticed that it did not need all=TRUE)

```
M1 <- merge(df1,melt(df2, id.var="X"), by.x="B", by.y="X")
subset(M1, value != "" , select=c(A,value, C) )
    A value C
1 ees   4k4 1
4 eeu   2ee 1
5 eeu   ooo 1
7 lee   3k3 1
8 lee   ggg 1
9 lee   vvv 1
```

Comment: But your newdf had more rows than he asked. And looking at the problem again I revised my answer so I do not get or need to test for NA.

Answer (score 3):

I would use melt() from the reshape package for this task.

```
 melt(df2, c("X"))
     X variable value
1  lee        Y   3k3
2  1su        Y   4k4
3  eeu        Y    5k
4  ggu        Y   2ee
5  lee        Z   ggg
6  1su        Z      
7  eeu        Z      
8  ggu        Z   ooo
9  lee       ZA   vvv
10 1su       ZA      
11 eeu       ZA      
12 ggu       ZA      

x <- melt(df2, c("X"))
x$variable <- NULL
x$C <- 1
colnames(x) <- c("A","B","C")
```

Now subset, and rbind()

```
x <- subset(x, B != "")
newdf <- rbind(df1, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is much better easy to do this...use the `match` function.

```
df1$Y <- df2$Y[match(df1$B, df2$X)]
```

You can expand it to other columns too.

Comment: I don't see how you would use this to add the additional rows. Can you expand your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
#example data.frames
d <- data.frame(a=c(1:10), b=c(1:10))
e <- data.frame(a=c(5:1), b=c(5:1))

#add row number of reference data.frame
d$row <- c(1:nrow(d))

#merge data.frames by desired columns
m<- merge.data.frame(d,e,by=c("a","b"))

#check results
m$row
d$row %in% m$row
```