# Extract all rows from df2 that match with info from 2 columns of df1

Tags: r

So I know that similar questions have been posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452205/subsetting-a-data-frame-based-on-contents-of-another-data-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352641/extract-data-from-one-data-frame-to-another-data-frame-with-different-row-length) but none of them seemed to work for my case.

So I have 2 df's:

**df1** is the smaller df that contains date, a stock and the corresponding number of trades of that stock, much like this:

```
date        | symbol  |trades    
05.01.2010  | AAPL    |34500   
05.01.2010  | AET     |26900  
05.01.2010  | ABL     |47300
```

**df2** is the bigger one, it contains date, stock and trades as well as 27 other characteristics:

```
date         |symbol| Correlation 2                     
2010-01-05   |AET   | 0,765    
2010-01-05   |ABL   | 0,315     
2010-01-05   |QXY   | 0,2157    
2010-01-05   |AAPL  | 0,31
```

Since I need to determine the correlation between values from a wide format of `df1` to `df2` I need to extract all those rows from df2 that match with date AND symbol from `df1`.
So all that is left in `df3` would be `AET` and `ABL`, but `QXY` never showed in `df1` so I don't need it in `df3` either.

The other measure that I would like to use for the correlation is in wide format(df1_wide), so I would need some code that would allow me to extract only the correlation 2 (with date and align it the same way as the symbols would be aligned) so I can swap the format to wide format as well and calculate my correlation (this would be df3_wide)

**Example of df1_wide:**

```
date        | AAPL  |   AET           
05.01.2010  | 34500 | 26900
```

**And for my correlation the corresponding df3_wide:**

```
date        | AAPL  |   AET       
05.01.2010  | 0,31  | 0,765
```

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you've tried and what you expect to see - some examples of code / data / output

Comment: This is the kind of plot I use to [record prey items](http://rpubs.com/RomanL/cat_restaurant) of my cats.

Comment: Dear Roman Lustrik, although I find your record very amusing and probably a nice way to teach statistics students, too, I don't seem to find a connection to my problem. :)

Comment: you need to set the same dates formats and then read carefully `merge`  it can do two merging on two keys as well. Give it a go, if you can't do it, I can help you. Try to paste some code from `dput(your_data_frame)` so it is easily reproducible.

Comment: I managed to change my dates into the same format using `buys$date <- dmy(as.character(buys$date))` and this
`data_panel$date <- ymd(as.character(data_panel$date))`. (buys = df1 and data_panel is df2). Using `newtable <- merge(data_panel,buys, by=c("date", "symbol"))` it finally worked. Thanks for the input @JanSila!

Comment: Great! Happy for you that you could do it on your own with a little hint. That makes you learn the most! Well done. I also put it as answer if you want to accept it :) Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the same dates formats and then read carefully merge it can do two merging on two keys as well. Give it a go, if you can't do it, I can help you. Try to paste some code from `dput(your_data_frame)` so it is easily reproducible.

Comment: I have a follow up question: `buys` (df 1) and `newtable` (df3) now contain the same values but not in the same order. I tried ordering for `date` and `symbol` via     `require(gdata)    
newtable$symbol <- reorder.factor(newtable$symbol, new.order=buys$symbol)` but this gives me back an error since some symbols are duplicates (but I need those duplicates, since they correspond to different dates).